# Pulley system with constraints

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, constrained-dynamics

[image]

Now I need to find out the acceleration of pulley A.

I know that (acceleration of a) = 2(acceleration of c) and the accelerations of A and C are in opposite directions using constraints.

The solution says that pulley C is in freefall and hence its acceleration is g (downwards) and therefore acceleration of A is 2g (upwards).

Why is pulley C in freefall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time homework questions are off-topic, but here you are asking a conceptual question where the homework question is just background. So I think it is a good/on-topic question.

In this case, start by looking at pulley A. Since pulley A is massless then in order for the acceleration of A to be finite, the net force on A must be 0. Because of the arrangement of the thread the net force on A is equal to the tension and directed upwards. Therefore the tension in the thread must be 0.

Once you know that the tension in the thread is 0 then looking at C it is clear that the only non-zero force acting on C is gravity. Therefore C is in free fall.